# Search Part of Cell for "String" and Replace Entire Cell Using Google Sheets Scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**Edit**

*Entered different characters for string to void confusion with row numbers*

I have a information written in some cells:

```
Column A                                            | Column B
Scrambled Egg with Toast x2 (Butter)                | Strawberry Smoothie x3 (Cream)
Banana Cake with Icing and Sprinkles x3 (Oven 180c) | Scrambled Egg with Toast x1 (Butter)
Strawberry Smoothie x3 (Cream)                      | Ice Cream and Waffles x3 (Freezer)
Ice Cream and Waffles x3 (Freezer)                  | Banana Cake with Icing and Sprinkles x3 (oven 180c)
```

I would like to some help to write a script that searches for (part) string in the columns above and replace the whole cell.

```
Finding: "Scrambled Egg"       | replacing entire cell with: "SE+T"
Finding: "Banana Cake"         | replacing entire cell with: "BC+IS"
Finding: "Strawberry Smoothie" | replacing entire cell with: "SS"
Finding: "Ice Cream"           | replacing entire cell with: "IC+W"
```

Resulting in:

**Before Search and Replace**

```
Column A                                            | Column B
Scrambled Egg with Toast x2 (Butter)                | Strawberry Smoothie x3 (Cream)
Banana Cake with Icing and Sprinkles x3 (Oven 180c) | Scrambled Egg with Toast x1 (Butter)
Strawberry Smoothie x3 (Cream)                      | Ice Cream and Waffles x3 (Freezer)
Ice Cream and Waffles x3 (Freezer)                  | Banana Cake with Icing and Sprinkles x3 (oven 180c)
```

**After Search and Replace**

```
Column A            | Column B
SE+T                | SS
BC+IS               | SE+T
SS                  | IC+W
IC+W                | BC+IS
```

.

.

I've looked around for various 'Find and Replace' solutions and ways to simplify the search and the answers found from
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60215088/loop-through-array-find-sub-string-in-cell-replace-text-in-google-sheets)
seemed to make sense however one returned only the first search:

```
function findReplace() {
  const ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srchA=['Scrambled Egg','Banana Cake','Strawberry Smoothie'];
  const vA=['SE+T','BC+IS','SS'];
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()-1);
  const v=rg.getValues();
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      srchA.forEach(function(s,k){
        if(v[i][j].toString().includes(s,k)) {
          sh.getRange(i+2,j+2).setValue(vA[k]);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

and the other didn't return any result.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var searchRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = searchRange.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = searchRange.getLastRow();

function findReplace() {
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn; i++){
    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow; j++){
      var value = rangeValues[j][i];
      if(typeof value != "string") { continue; }
      if(value.indexOf("Scrambled Egg") > -1){
        var newValue = value.replace("Scrambled Egg", "SE+T")
        sheet.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(newValue);
      }
      else if (value.indexOf("Banana Cake") > -1){
        var newValue = value.replace("Banana Cake", "BC+IS")
        sheet.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(newValue);
      }
      else if (value.indexOf("Strawberry Smoothie") > -1){
        var newValue = value.replace("Strawberry Smoothie", "SS")
        sheet.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(newValue);
      }; 
    };
  };
};
```

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwUdTMQJbKbJFpO64TaGd_BZ848ebdDeNT1OKhIGk2Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why is row 4 in column B yellow, why not Blue?

Comment: Hello @CodeCamper, I apologise. There are no row labels so _row 4_ in _Column B_ has the string **"Four Three"** so when the search is made `"Four"` is what would change the cell to **"Yellow"**. Will try to use different characters to make it more readable. Thanks

Comment: @CodeCamper, Hopefully the edits made makes this a little clearer. Please also take a look at the Sample Sheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to do the operation you are looking for:

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(map($D$1:$D$4,lambda(fox,If(iserror(find(fox,A3)),"",if(find(fox,A3) ,indirect("E"&row(fox)),0))))))
```

Replace d1:d4 with the first column of your before text and make sure the second column is the replace text, replace a3 with the cell you want to replace.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. However, have tried to follow your suggestion as best and have received no result. Is it also possible to use script?

Comment: @SCTJ you need to make a table with the before and after changes ‘d1’ needs to say ‘Scrambled Egg’ and ‘e1’ needs to say ‘SE+T’  ‘a3’ needs to say ‘Scrambled Egg with Toast x2 (Butter)’

Comment: @SCTJ if that doesn’t help please show me the sheet where you are trying to use the formula

Comment: Thanks @CodeCamper. Have adjusted your instructions though it doesn't return all results. Sheet as requested (also found at end of question, just in case.) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwUdTMQJbKbJFpO64TaGd_BZ848ebdDeNT1OKhIGk2Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SCTJ just drag the formula down